# Should I check DynamoDB map update path before sending

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am storing data in DynamoDB as a Map attribute type and implementing a restful PATCH endpoint to modify that data (RFC 6902).

In my validation routine, I am currently NOT making sure that the Map exists before translating the patch into an updating expression and sending it to DynamoDB.

This means that if the Map is not already set in DynamoDB, the update will fail (ValidationException since the document path does not exist).

My Question: is it appropriate/acceptable/OK to rely on DynamoDB rejecting the update in this way, or should I get a copy of the item and reject the patch in my own validation routines?

I have not been able to think of a reason not to allow DynamoDB the pleasure of rejecting the patch (and it saves me a GET call), but it makes me a little nervous to rely on a 3rd party validation like this (although we specify the API version now when accessing AWS so in theory this should always work...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a highly subjective question, yet personally I don't see the benefit of doing your own validation by adding an extra round-trip to DynamoDB when, the way I see it, the worst that can happen is the update succeeding to DynamoDB.  This is no different than treating a local database update that returns success as authoritative.

And if you're worried about long-term backwards compatibility (ie. DynamoDB API contract changing from underneath you) then hopefully you've written some functional/integration tests that are run periodically and specifically whenever you update your software dependencies.

Comment: Agreed this is somewhat subjective - my purpose was to see if there was a consensus on this type of behavior in general. Your thinking mirrored my own and I appreciate your response.